# How can I find my Google Account name?

Tags: google-account

I can't remember the name of one of my Google accounts (account a), but it was signed in on a computer that was signed in to a different account (account b). is there a way to find account a in the history of account b?

Comment: most likely not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Account B's email address was set as an alternate login or as the recovery address for Account A, you would have received an email message to that effect when you created the account.

Beyond that, no, there's no way for a mortal to connect two disparate Google accounts.

Comment: that's actually what happened thankfully